# how to fetch req.params whatever it was

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on a url shortener api. The problem i'm facing is that if I pass a parameter like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ` then `req.params.url` will only be equal to `https://www.youtube.com/watch`. I've looked a lot on stackoverflow and all the answers are similar but not what I'm looking for.

I want to parse the `url` parameter and get the characters it contains.

This is the URI i'm using right now

```
router.route('/add/:url(*)')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
app.get(/[/]add[/].*/, function (req, res) {

    var uri = req.originalUrl.replace(/^[/][^/]*[/]*/, '');
    console.log(uri);
    res.end();

});
```

Comment: thanks alot . that solved the problem . but i'm wondering why there are 5 downvotes on my question ?

Comment: @BahaaZidan Good to know, I'm glad it helped. I don't know why there are 5 downvotes - now you have one upvote. ;)

Comment: I'm betting the downvotes came in part from the use of ALL CAPS in the original.  I edited the tone of your question, because I think it's a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're wanting the `query` part of the URL? Take a look at [`req.query`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) docs (and other parts of the request) and read about the parts of the [URI](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-glossary-url-definitions/) or more formal definitions on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier).  Having the correct names will help you understand the Express.js docs.

From express.js docs:

```
// GET /search?q=tobi+ferret
req.query.q
// => "tobi ferret"
```

From wikipedia:

```
 scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]
```